# Redux state single item update showing previous version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My update reducer for my items (icdCode) in my array (icdCodes) is not updating properly within the react component (until I reload the entire component). First it was giving the duplicate key issue because the newly updated item in the array was showing up along with the previous state item within my list component after the action was triggered. I figured a workaround for that with some tweaks, but no matter what else I've tried, I can't update this item properly on the front-end.

Initial state:

```
state = {icdCodes: []}
```

The update reducer:

```
case UPDATE_ICD_CODE:
return {
        ...state,
        icdCodes: [...state.icdCodes, action.payload]
}
```

Here's an excerpt from my react component loading the list of these array items (via mapping):

```
  render() {
    const { icdCodes } = this.props.icdCode;

    return (
      <Card body>
        <ListGroup flush>
              <Row>
                this.icdCodes.map(({ _id, icdCode, icdCodeValue }) => (
                <div>{icdCodeValue}</div>
                )
              </Row>
        </ListGroup>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

IcdCodeItem.propTypes = {
  getIcdCodes: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  icdCode: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  icdCode: state.icdCode
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getIcdCodes, deleteIcdCode, updateIcdCode }
)(IcdCodeItem);
```

Here is what the action.payload returns (the updated icdCode item with a new value in place of the "icdCode" section):

```
{icdCodeVersion: "10", 
_id: "5b922fbae1c4241b54ea8aa4", 
icdCode: "I9", 
icdCodeValue: "jam jam", 
date: "2018-09-07T07:58:50.104Z", …}
```

The following code only partly solves the issue (allows me to edit only the first key (not the icdCode item, but the icdCode within the item - apologies for the horrible syntax) of my object rather than the whole object):

```
return {
        ...state,
        icdCodes: state.icdCodes.map(
          icdCode =>
            icdCode._id === action.payload._id
              ? { ...icdCode, icdCode: action.payload.icdCode }
              : icdCode
        )
      };
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `UPDATE_ICD_CODE`? Is it updating an element or adding one? How is your payload's shape? Can you put your app to codesandbox.io if possible?

Comment: Your last try is a little bit weird. You are mapping an array, then if the element is equal to 0, then returning an object by spreading it but assigning its name as a property again to your payload.

Comment: @devserkan it is the update method in my reducer for the icdCode state (array of icdCodes in the redux store). I am only trying to update one entry in the icdCode object. The update persists to the database, but the redux reducer isn't updating the individual item, it is only adding the updated item as an extra item in my list of icdCode items. My action.payload returns the updated icdCode item which is an object. I'll update my code to add that snippet.

Comment: So, only `icdCode` part is changing, right? Then you will replace the same object with this new one?

Comment: Exactly, only that specific icdCode item that is being edited from the array in the react icdCodeItem component. My issue arose when I began to manipulate the two separate icdCode item fields separately (only updating one key of the object at a time).

Comment: Also, I edited the post to show a new tweak I tried that is giving me the correct update, but only for one key of the icdCode item that is being edited.

Comment: I've provided an answer. I hope it works. It's too late here, maybe I misunderstood something :) If so, either someone else suggests something or I can check it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `icdCodes` array, then if the element is right (here I'm checking by `_id`) then you can change it without mutating.

```
case UPDATE_ICD_CODE: {
  const icdCodes = state.icdCodes.map(icd => {
    if (icd._id === action.payload._id) {
      return { ...icd, icdCode: action.payload.icdCode };
    }
    return icd;
  });

  return { ...state, icdCodes };
}
```

** Update after comments **

If you need to change more than one property here it is:

```
case UPDATE_ICD_CODE: {
  const { _id, icdCode, icdCodeValue } = action.payload;
  const icdCodes = state.icdCodes.map(icd => {
    if (icd._id === _id) {
      return { ...icd, icdCode, icdCodeValue };
    }
    return icd;
  });

  return { ...state, icdCodes };
}
```

If you want to change the object totally, it is easier:

```
case UPDATE_ICD_CODE: {
    const { _id } = action.payload;
    const icdCodes = state.icdCodes.map(icd =>
        icd._id === _id ? action.payload : icd
    )

    return { ...state, icdCodes };
}
```

Comment: Ok this is almost perfect, now my only issue is that this only works for updating the first field in the icdCode object (icdCode - I should've called this icdCodeNumber to avoid the confusion), but not the second field (icdCodeValue). How could I tweak the code to update the entire object rather than the specific icdCode field?

Comment: I'm confused with the names :) We are changing here one object's property in your array. It is `icdCode` property. So, how do you plan to change `icdCodeValue` with your payload?

Comment: Also, I've checked your updated solution. It is the same with mine here :) You are using ternary operator there I am using regular if block.

Comment: Lol I don't blame you, it is not written properly. The object is basically icdCode: { icdCode: "some number", icdCodeValue: "the numbers defined value"}. So I would like to handle the change to both the fields at once in the reducer. Currently, it would only change the "icdCode" fields value in the icdCode object.

Comment: OK. So, new payload holds this new `icdCodeValue` as well as `icdCode` right?

Comment: Yes =] exactly. My payload itself contains the full icdCode object that is being edited. Should I just replace the icdCode with icd? as follows: `return { ...icd, icd: action.payload };` EDIT: that didn't work =/

Comment: Ok, easy peasy. Last question, do you want to keep anything from the old icdCode object or replacing it with the new one is totally fine?

Comment: Replacing it should be totally fine since it only has two properties. But I would be curious (just to know for future reference) conceptually what would be different if I only put the changed item?

Comment: Wait. The new object has only two properties or it has two different (changed) properties?

Comment: Currently, I am handling the changes via separate functions, so once one property is changed, I just attach the other unchanged property along with it and send the full object to the reducer with it. So they would be changed individually (not ideal, but I couldn't figure a workaround with the library I am using for editing the fields).

Comment: But, you can change two properties here with the new payload. Maybe since it is too late (7am and no sleep yet) maybe something else I can't quite understand how you get the new object :) But, at the end of the day if your reducer gets the final object and you want to replace it with the old one, you can just replace the object itself. No need to struggle with properties. I'm still a learner but in DB operations people always do this. To update, first, manipulate the data, then create a new one with this, then pass it back to change the old one. The state is not different I think.

Comment: nevermind, I finally got it buddy: `{ ...icd, icdCode: action.payload.icdCode, icdCodeValue: action.payload.icdCodeValue }`

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm saying, easy peasy :) I was going to provide an update. Let me do it :)

Comment: I already selected your answer as correct from when you first posted. Thank you so much for your help and for staying up so late to help me man. Appreciate the help a lot man I hope you sleep well tonight/morning brother!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome. I saw you accepted it in the first time but doing it to the end is important :)